# PyQt threading application crashes at random point with no error messages

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a PyQt GUI application that will just randomly crash and will not produce an error message at all. The crashes are not consistent. Sometimes it happens immediately and then other times it won't happen for a day or two. I have looked online and I believe that it is a threading issue but I haven't been able to trace down where. I've included an example below. My original program is too large to paste here but the threading I am doing in the smaller example is the exact same way I am handling threading in my larger application.

I need to use signals and emit them instead of accessing the main thread, but I am not sure how I would actually do that.

main.py

```
import logging
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

logger_real_time = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ConsoleWindowLogHandler(logging.Handler, QObject):
    sigLog = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, log_record):
        message = str(log_record.getMessage())
        self.sigLog.emit(message)


class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        self.func(*self.args)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.ui = self.load_ui()
        self.bee = Worker(self.start_a_process, ())
        self.run_main_gui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        current_path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(current_path)
        if ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
            self.ui = loader.load(ui_file, self)
            ui_file.close()
            return self.ui

    def start_a_process(self):
        print('sleeping')
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.ui.a_text_edit.append("Entering function")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.ui.a_text_edit.append("Exiting function")

    def run_main_gui(self):
        self.ui.start_pb.clicked.connect(self.bee.start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook


    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback_val):
        print(exctype, value, traceback_val)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback_val)
        sys.exit(1)


    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

form.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'form.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        if not Widget.objectName():
            Widget.setObjectName(u"Widget")
        Widget.resize(310, 184)
        self.start_pb = QPushButton(Widget)
        self.start_pb.setObjectName(u"start_pb")
        self.start_pb.setGeometry(QRect(100, 40, 93, 28))
        self.a_text_edit = QTextEdit(Widget)
        self.a_text_edit.setObjectName(u"a_text_edit")
        self.a_text_edit.setGeometry(QRect(10, 80, 291, 87))

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Widget", u"Widget", None))
        self.start_pb.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Widget", u"Start", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe. You cannot directly access them from external threada. Use signals.

Comment: @musicamante yes I see that often times with these posts but no one ever explains what that means or how to fix it

Comment: @Luke The usual explanation is simply that *Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread*. So don't do that. The normal fix is to use signals (which are thread-safe) to communicate with the main thread (as already pointed out above, and [many, many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+thread+signals)).

Comment: @Luke as ekhumoro showed, there already *hundreds* of related posts, we don't explain it every time because otherwise we'd have thousands of fundamentally *identical* posts, as we see these questions almost on a daily basis. Besides, it seems like you're already using signals, so it's not really clear what else should be said about this, unless you were using code taken from elsewhere (which is perfectly fine) and didn't try to understand what it does/how/why (which is *not*).

Comment: @Luke Moreover, even if they do similar things, PyQt and PySide are ***not*** the same, and ***cannot*** be used together. They use different ways of wrapping and accessing C++ objects, so using both is unreliable and **always** discouraged. You either use one or the other, using both will sooner or later create issues and possibly make your program unstable and extremely prone to crashes.

Comment: @musicamante Yes I am already using signals which is where my confusion comes in personally. I based this code off of the other guides on the internet yes, but I have written most of it and can go line by line and say what everything does. My confusion comes in to play because I am already emitting the signal out within my ConsoleWindowHandler so I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Luke You're directly calling `Widget.start_a_process` in `Worker.run`, which attempts to update a text-edit. Instead, you need to define a custom signal for `Worker`, connect it to `start_a_process`, and emit the signal to update the text-edit. Also, you ***must*** replace the PyQt imports with PySide ones (or *vice versa*) - you cannot use both together. Note also that your code never creates an instance of `ConsoleWindowLogHandler`, so it will obviously never emit any messages.